# How to do an HTML select form where the selected option update a JSON value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I currently have one HTML+JS webpage where I hard code the starting condition (the West, North, East, South geographic coordinate of a country) :

```
var WNES = { "W": 67.0, "N":37.5, "E": 99.0, "S": 5.0, "item":"India" };
```

I however just datamined data for ~180 countries, so I also have :

```
var WSEN_list = [
    {"W":60.504050405040545;"S":29.306134923492337;"E":75.1575157515752;"N":38.47551472547255;"item":"Afghanistan"},
    {"W":11.611161116111646;"S":-17.94743030603061;"E":24.068406840684105;"N":-4.453854347434742;"item":"Angola"},
    {"W":19.279927992799315;"S":39.62168720072006;"E":21.00810081008106;"N":42.67814713471347;"item":"Albania"},
    {...}
];
```

I want my end-user to pick a country using a html `<select>` element :

```
<form>
Select your country:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Afghanistan</option>
  <option>Albania</option>
  <option>Angola</option>
</select>
</form>
```

then, to store the user's selected item value (by exemple "Angola"), so I can use this key to search my list of data and state :

```
var WNES = {"W":11.611161116111646;"S":-17.94743030603061;"E":24.068406840684105;"N":-4.453854347434742;"item":"Angola"};
```

**How to do a such select button and system which update my WNES from the WSEN_list ?**

---

**Solution:** see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UUm69/2/)

Comment: Nothing, I don't know what to look for. Indications welcome.

Comment: Can you change the data structure to make it as simple as ` var locations = { "Afghanistan" : { "W": ....}, "India" : { "W" : ...} };` That means no looping over an object, it is as simple as `locations[text]`

Comment: You can use index of location in `WSEN_list` as value of each option.

Comment: @epascarello: so I may have something like : `var country_name = selected_value`, and then `var WNES = WSEN_list.country_name`.

Comment: I've implemented it for you in pure js, [take a look here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mCrWmYQRGqfxw4vIHidb?p=preview) @LeGEC beat me to an answer, so I won't add another :)

Comment: no, you need to use bracket notation like I used above. `WSEN_list[country_name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to react to the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event on your `#mySelect` node :

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    // this code will be executed each time the selection change

    // you can get the selected country like this :
    var country = this.value;

    // do whatever you want with this value
});
```

Comment: Yes, I'am looking for something like that.

Comment: Your system + @epascarello datastructure change sound like the solution.